# converting log files from McPAT to Hotspot format showing error in python

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, hotspot, gem5

I am following a tutorial in this link https://github.com/danielpalomino/mcpat-hotspot-parser

when I run this command to output power value in the hotspot format

```
python mcpat-hotspot-parser mcpat.log
```

it shows this me error

```
/usr/bin/python: can't find '__main__' module in 'mcpat-hotspot-parser'
```

I run this command on ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Also consider contacting McPAT maintainers/that tutorial's maintainer directly on their channels.